# Modify Flux type

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, proxy, spring-webflux

I have got a Flux<CollectionDetail> that contains below data structure.

```
[
    {
        "id": 181,
        "date": "2020-06-25T14:49:04",
        "status": "publish",
        "type": "wprm_collection",
        "link": "http://35.228.92.155/?post_type=wprm_collection&p=181",
        "collection": {
            "id": 181,
            "name": "Menu-4",
            "nbrItems": "3",
            "items": {}
        }
    },
    {...},
    {...},
    {...}
]
```

Below code is not able to retrieve the subobject and provide a new flux out of it.

```
public Flux<Collection> getWeeklyMenus() {
        System.out.println("Calling WP");

        Mono<List<CollectionDetail>> collectionDetailList = client.get()
                .uri("/wprm_collection")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(CollectionDetail.class).collectList();

        List<Collection> collections = new ArrayList();
        collectionDetailList.flatMap(items->{
            for(CollectionDetail item : items){
                Collection collection = item.getCollection();
                collections.add(collection);
            }
            return null;
        });

        return Mono.just(collections).flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable);
    }
```

How can I convert Flux<CollectionElement> to Flux<Collection> without blocking the stream for this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about not extracting the list calling `collectList()` and work directly on `Flux`?

Solution:

```
public Flux<Collection> getWeeklyMenus() {
    Flux<CollectionDetail> collectionDetailList = client.get()
            .uri("/wprm_collection")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(CollectionDetail.class);

    return collectionDetailList
            .map(CollectionDetail::getCollection);
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way that I can retrieve CollectionDetail so that I can perform some more operations, say removing some noise data from Collection and add some other?

Comment: You can always use `filter` in chain to remove some elements. To add new elements you can take a look on `merge` and `concat` operators